# SQL Server trigger for insert or updated

Tags: sql-server, gis

I am trying to edit the table `EditingField_Poly` and column `Send_Email` from 'Yes' to 'No'. It doesn't let me save the editing... When I disable the trigger, it lets me save. This trigger is supposed to see if there is new insert or any updated for those 2 columns -- if there is then it will change status in the `Send_Email` column from "No" to "Yes"

Can someone help me what I did wrong with this trigger?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Send_Email]
ON [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    IF (UPDATE([Status]) or UPDATE([Department]))
    BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;

          DECLARE @OID int;
          SELECT @OID = i.OBJECTID from inserted i;

          UPDATE [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY] 
          SET Send_Email = 'Yes' 
          WHERE OBJECTID = @OID            
END
GO
```

Comment: can you post the table structure?

Comment: Are you _only_ setting the `Send_Email` field or are there multiple fields being set in the `SET` portion? If either `Status` or `Department` are in the `SET` clause, then your trigger will fire, even if their values aren't changing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't let save the editing"? Do you receive any error or message?

Comment: Anytime there is an new insert or an update to field "Status" and "Department" then it will put a "Yes" in "Send_Email" field which then another script kick in to send an email.

Comment: There is an issue on your trigger which will cause problem if you have a batch update. you should know that, trigger runs once per statement not per update. if you update 10 records using one update statement, your trigger will run once and "instered" symbol will contains 10 row and your "SELECT @OID....." will fail. This might not be the issue, but you need to pay attention to it

Comment: After it sent it changed from "Yes" to "No"... In this case, I try to edit that in Arcmap to change the field "Yes" to "No", it doesn't let me do that and it might be the reason why I keep getting repeating email because it didn't change "Yes" to No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is **severely flawed** because it assumes only one row in `Inserted` - this is not always the case. If your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operation affects multiple rows, the trigger is called *only once* for the whole statement, and the pseudo tables will contain **multiple rows**!

You need to work with that knowledge, and write your trigger in a *fully set-based* fashion - not using any `SELECT @OID = Inserted.ObjectID` style code!

Also, since you're checking in the `UPDATE` case whether one of two rows has changed, you cannot easily do this in a combined trigger - I'd recommend using two separate triggers, one for `INSERT`, one for `UPDATE`.

Try this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Send_Email_Update]
ON [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY] 
    SET Send_Email = 'Yes' 
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.OBJECTID = d.OBJECTID
    WHERE [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY].OBJECTID = i.OBJECTID
      AND (d.Status <> i.Status OR d.Department <> i.Department)
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Send_Email_Insert]
ON [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY]
FOR INSERT
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY] 
    SET Send_Email = 'Yes' 
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE [dbo].[EDITINGFIELD_POLY].OBJECTID = i.OBJECTID
GO
```

Comment: If my OBJECTID is PK then what happen?

Comment: @Lanna: I just updated my response - just a tiny change to the first trigger. Should work just fine

Comment: I did that and there is no "END" and it give me this error: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_Send_Email_Update, Line 10
Ambiguous column name 'OBJECTID'.

Comment: @Lanna: added the disambiguation

Comment: And for future readers, even if you think that you will only ever insert/update one record at a time, over time this will prove false close to 100% of the time. It is a bad practice to ever write any trigger without considering what will happen in multiple records are involved.

Comment: @Marc_S: The trigger for the update work but for INSERT it not working-- before I thought it work but the field default is Yes, allow Null No then it  it work without the insert trigger but when I publish to the web, it is not... if I change the field format from allow Null to Yes and turn on the insert trigger it is not working.. Is there something in the trigger insert that missing? Thanks